# why does react code for 'hello React' not working

Tags: reactjs, components

my simple react component is not working

Instructor in the video has exact code but its not working for me. I've tried several different combinations including putting the code in a separate .js file and using src attribute to link but nothing seems to be working.

Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" 
        crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" 
        crossorigin></script>           
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>       
        <script type="text/jsx">  
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello, React</h1>,
                document.getElementById('container')
            );      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

nothing is rendering on the page

Comment: I get this warning in my console: [Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.

Comment: I was actually missing link to **babel** as pointed out by Olivier below. It worked fine after link to babel was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) is not understandable by default by the browser. You need a tool like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your JSX code (`<h1>Hello, React</h1>`) into valid **ES5 javascript code** which will be understandable by the browsers.

To make your example work correctly, simply add the following line `<script src="<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.4.4/babel.min.js"></script>"></script>`

Note that this solution is only valid for testing small examples, you should consider [other solutions](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project) in production

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" 
       crossorigin></script>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" 
       crossorigin></script>      
        
       <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.4.4/babel.min.js">
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>       
        <script type="text/jsx">  
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello, React</h1>,
                document.getElementById('container')
            );      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```